# Как записать класс в std::vector<BYTE>

Tags: c++, классы, vector, c++14

Есть:

```
class Token {
    public:
        // DON'T DISTURB THE ORDER!!!
        lu  dist;
        hu length;
        BYTE character;
        // DON'T DISTURB THE ORDER!!!
    };
```

И указатель на пустой вектор: `std::vector<BYTE>* block`, где BYTE - unsigned char

Вопрос: Как записать `Token` в `block` и обратно

Comment: Взять адрес переменной типа Token и ее размер (`sizeof()`). Присвоить этот адрес указателю `unsigned char *`. Затем записать в цикле в вектор байты по этому указателю. Ничего сверхординарного

Comment: @avp а поподробней можно, как это сделать. "Ничего сверхординарного" - это если знать, что делать

Comment: `Token t; unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&t; for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Token); i++) v.push_back(p[i]);`

Comment: Или `.resize`, а потом `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку `Token` является типом [простой структуры данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), то объекты этого класса можно скопировать при помощи `memcpy`.

```
std::vector<BYTE>* block; // указывает на существующий вектор
Token token; // существующий объект

// Выделяем достаточно памяти чтобы поместить объект.
block->resize(sizeof(Token));

// Поскольку вектор изначально пустой мы можем писать в его начало.
std::memcpy(&block->at(0), &token, sizeof(Token));
```

А затем для чтения обратно можно опять использовать `memcpy`:

```
Token token2; // в него будет скопирован объект
std::memcpy(&token2, &block->at(0), sizeof(Token));
```

Пример можно посмотреть тут:
http://cpp.sh/5xm7u

---

Но это решение имеет свои ограничения. Одно из самых больших - данные не переносимые. То есть на системах с другими размерами базовых типов и другим порядком байтов значения не будут теми же.
Если цель - передача данных на другую систему, то стоит использовать системы сериализации. Например, [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) или просто `json`.

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться членом `.data()`?

Comment: @Harry можете предложить свой ответ ^_^

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Зачем? Он полностью совпадает с приведенным, я только уточнил, что логичнее использовать специально для этого предназначенную [функцию-член](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

Comment: @Harry почему обязательно `resize()` - можно ли использовать `reserve()` ?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Нет, потому что это выделение памяти не под данные, а под будущие выделения с помощью того же `resize()` или `push_back()`. А `resize()` выделяет элементы для хранения реальных данных.

Comment: @Harry я сначала хотел предложить `data()`, но потом подумал что `at()` будет лучше масштабироваться, например, если нужно будет добавить смещение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо